Disable tests on Jakarta-mail 1.6.5
I am trying to build jakarta-mail 1.6.5 but my build failed on tests. I don't know Java well, so I want to try disable all tests on project. Tell me please how I can do that?
I try to comment some section with "test" label on mail-1.6.5/mail/pom.xml but is's didn't work.
https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api/tree/1.6.5

The 1.6.7 is the latest official release of that 1.x branch and will fail on JDK21.  The snapshot version should work though https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api/commits/v1.x/

You can run the build with mvn install -DskipTests to skip over any unit/integration tests there.

I try to build rpm package jakarta-mail using .spec file adn rpmbuild+mock tools. So I look at this .spec file and find some similar sections:
%build
%mvn_build -j

%install
%mvn_install

I tried to add -DskipTests after %mvn_build -j and %mvn_install but it didn't work.

/usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/java-utils/mvn_build.py --xmvn-javadoc -j -DskipTests
Usage: mvn_build.py [options] [-- maven-arguments]
mvn_build.py: error: no such option: -D
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.AkGbJJ (%build)


Sorry for this shit comment. I didn't know how to insert code correctly
